# Wildcards in the singularity field of snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Does anyone know whether it is possible to use "wildcards" and/or the "param" variable under the “singularity” (container) field ?

I figured out that it is possible to use "globally" defined variables but I could not use yet variables that are local to the rule (e.g. wildcards).

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with using singularity with (or without) snakemake. Can you give a code example of what you mean by *use "wildcards" and/or the "param" variable under the “singularity” (container) field*

Comment: It is possible to declare the usage of a docker or singularity container for each rule by the "container" or "singularity" field. The value of this field is, for example, a URI to the image (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#running-jobs-in-containers)